# Marginal distribution from conditional Gauss and arbitrary distribution

Tags: probability

Let $Z\sim p_z$ some distribution (density) and $p(x|z)=\mathcal{N}(f(z),\sigma^2 I)$ where $f$ is a deterministic function (with reasonable smoothness properties) and $\sigma>0$. Does then hold that $X\sim f(Z)+\epsilon$ where $Z\sim p_z$ and $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I)$?

It seems to be true and a proof with the total law of expectation seems reasonable, but I can't figure it out on my own.

Any help/hints are appreciated!

EDIT: any relations between the random variables that are not explicitly mentioned can assumed to be independent.

Comment: You want to prove that $X = f(Z) + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2 I)$?

Comment: I want to prove that $X$ has the same distribution as $f(Z)+\epsilon$ where $Z\sim p_z$ and $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I)$. Maybe this formulation is better: $X=^d f(Z)+\epsilon$

Comment: True if epsilon Z are independent

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Could you give me an idea on how to proof that or why that is true? The fact could be very obvious, but I am lacking intuition regarding conditionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $U \overset{\mathcal F}{\sim} V$, i.e. the regular conditional distributions $\mu_U(\omega,\cdot) = \mu_V(\omega,\cdot)$ agree for $\omega \in \Omega$. Then $P(U\in B) = E(P(U\in B \mid \mathcal F)) = E(P(V\in B \mid \mathcal F)) = P(V\in B)$. We conclude $U \overset{d}{=} V$.

Now, $f(Z)+\epsilon$ conditional on $Z$ has regular conditional distribution $\mathcal N(f(\tilde Z), \sigma^2 I)$ where $\tilde Z \sim \delta_Z$. Note we have used the independence of $\epsilon$ and $Z$ here. This is Lemma 8.7 of Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability 3e: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-61871-1.

Hence $X \overset{Z}{\sim} f(Z)+\epsilon$, implying $X\overset{d}{=} f(Z)+\epsilon$.

Comment: Does $\delta_Z$ denote the point mass on some value of $Z$?

Comment: Yup, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon = X-f(Z)$ you want to prove that $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2 I)$. You can do that by considering the characteristic function, indeed,

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[e^{i \left\langle \epsilon, u\right\rangle}\right] &= \mathbb E\left[e^{i \left\langle X - f(Z), u\right\rangle}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{i \left\langle X-f(Z), u\right\rangle}\Big | Z\right]\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{-i \left\langle f(Z), u\right\rangle}\mathbb E\left[e^{i \left\langle X, u\right\rangle}\Big | Z\right]\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{-i \left\langle f(Z), u\right\rangle}e^{i\langle f(Z), u\rangle - \frac12\sigma^2\left\|u\right\|^2}\right] = e^{-\frac12 \sigma^2 \left\|u\right\|^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you! However, I accepted Andrews answer since it answers my question in a (I think) more general way (using that if all conditional distributions agree, the distributions agree).